# Regex to exactly match the characters of a word in any random order, without duplicated characters

Tags: java, regex, string, random, match

Let's say I have a String, and I want to check if it matches another String in any possible (random) order. For example, let's say I have a String `s`, and I want to check if it matches `"ONE"` in a random order (== one of the following: `ENO|EON|NEO|NOE|OEN|ONE`, but not `EEE;EEN;EEO;`etc.)

In a more general description: I'm looking for a regex to match a String in a random order, with only the given characters of that String (this means the String itself can contain duplicated character, like `SEVEN`, but should use exactly two `E`'s in the random matching, and not more or less).

I know I could use a literal `ENO|EON|NEO|NOE|OEN|ONE` to match `ONE`, and the same for `TWO` through `NINE`, but this is way too long..
I also know I can match everything including duplicated characters like this `[ONE]{3}`, but then it will also incorrectly matches `EEE`, `EEN`, and such.

I know I could also just create a loop to generate all these different permutations, and append them together with a `|` delimiter. And I think that might also be a valid solution in this case. But if this is possible with a regex I'd like to know as well for my own knowledge. Oh, and even if it's with a loop I also don't want it to be too long (since I'm actually asking this because of a code-golf challenge, where you solve a certain challenge in as few bytes as possible).

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this with "normal" regex - sounds like you need to perform fuzzy matching, which AFAIK none of the standard regex engines support

Comment: What is wrong with just doing something like `for(char c in "ONE") if(count(c, "ONE") != count(c, str) return false;`? That way, you don't have to write a regex for every word. (also, this is basically a much more efficient version of what the regex would compile to do anyways)

Comment: @Tezra That's indeed a good alternative as well. Although a regex is in this case preferably, due to something I forgot to mention in the question. It should match part of complete String. So a String could be something like this: `"ENOWOT"` and it should return `"12"`. I didn't mention this because I already have a solving strategy in my head, which required a regex like _Casimir et Hippolyte_ provided. [Here is the Codegolf challenge btw, for anyone wondering what I wanted to achieve.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131852/the-original-number)

Comment: If that was a speed challenge, I would just go with a tree parse (as no 1 digit number is a sub-string of another); similar to how file decompression works. Since it is code size, the above non-regex would just need a while loop to iterate sub-strings and a for-each over the number words 1-9.

Comment: @Tezra I tried what you said, but it ends up at 299 bytes. I'm sure it can be golfed a bit more, but my current answer with the regex is 256 bytes. [Link in ideone - since the url is shorter than TIO..](https://ideone.com/PR0EQ5) Creating the `count(...)` method you've proposed in-line, which isn't a native Java method, takes up more byte than predicted. I have to loop over the characters of the String-number (i.e. `"ONE"`), and use `s.substring(...).split(t=""+c,-1).length==n.split(t,-1).length`; where `s`=input; `n`=String-number; `c`=current character; `t`=temp-String to golf some bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it putting conditions in lookaheads. For ONE:

```
\b(?=\w*O)(?=\w*N)(?=\w*E)[ONE]{3}\b
```

For SEVEN:

```
\b(?=\w*S)(?=\w*E\w*E)(?=\w*V)(?=\w*N)[SEVN]{5}\b
```

To improve the performance in a large text, you can test the letters and the length at the beginning of the pattern:

```
\b(?=[ONE]{3}\b)(?=\w*O)(?=\w*N)\w*E\w*
```

or:

```
\b(?=[SEVN]{5}\b)(?=\w*S)(?=\w*E\w*E)(?=\w*V)\w*N\w*
```

This way, words that contains other letters or words that don't have the good length are quickly discarded.

You can also put the less efficient conditions at the end:

```
\b(?=[SEVN]{5}\b)(?=\w*S)(?=\w*V)(?=\w*N)\w*E\w*E\w*
```

To finish, you can also reduce the backtracking using negated character classes:

```
\b(?=[SEVN]{5}\b)(?=[^\WS]*S)(?=[^\WV]*V)(?=[^\WN]*N)[^\WE]*E[^\WE]*E\w*
```

or using other letters:

```
\b(?=[SEVN]{5}\b)(?=[EVN]*S)(?=[SEN]*V)(?=[SEV]*N)[SVN]*E[SVN]*E\w*
```

Comment: Thanks! And great answer by providing all these other alternatives. With regex there are always multiple solutions for the same problem in my experience, and it's great to see you've given better alternatives regarding performance. +1 and accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think, regex can not do that.

Use a `map< Integer,Integer>` to count your chars, and verify, or just an array (faster).

Comment: or a `Map<Character,Integer>` perhaps?

Comment: @MauricePerry. Yes !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can construct your regex to make it like this `^(?=[ONE]{3}$)(?=.*O).*(?=.*N).*(?=.*E).*$` [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/krgUbU/1), so you can use something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = new String[]{"ENOE", "ENO", "EON", "NEO", "NOE", "OEN", 
        "ONE", "OOO"};
    Main m = new Main();
    String word = "ONE";// This can be any word you want to matche
    String regex = m.getPattern(word);
    System.out.println(regex);
    for (String s : strings) {
        if (s.matches(regex)) {
            System.out.println("matches : " + s);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not matches : " + s);
        }
    }
}

// I use Java 8 to create the pattern it is more helpful
private String getPattern(String word) {
    StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
    //^(?=[ONE]{3}$)
    pattern.append("^(?=[").append(word).append("]{").append(word.length()).append("}$)");
    Arrays.asList(word.split("")).stream()
            .map(t -> "(?=.*" + t + ").*")
            .forEach(pattern::append);
    pattern.append("$");
    return pattern.toString();// result (?=.*O).*(?=.*N).*(?=.*E).*
}
```

**Outputs**

```
Not matches : ENOE
matches : ENO
matches : EON
matches : NEO
matches : NOE
matches : OEN
matches : ONE
Not matches : OOO
```

Comment: this matches OOO

Comment: what about now @marvel308 ?

Comment: matches ONEE you can improve by restricting the length

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following regex if the characters in the string are unique

```
^(?=[ONE]{3}$)(?=.*O).*(?=.*N).*(?=.*E).*$
```

you can see a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/DgubiD/1)

the regex works as follows [image]

Basically it matches a 3 letter word which consists of letters from **[ONE]** and makes sure that all 3 occur in the resulting string

Comment: This answer would be much better if it included some kind of explanation.

Comment: Updated answer and added an explanation